# How to create an editable input tabel using flask

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

I'm new to Flask and I would like to give an app (powered by flask) some input by an tabel and write the input into an json file and safe it local by hitting a button.  Is there a way without a database, maybe just with javascript?

**How the tabel should look like:** It should be an dynamic tabel like there are at loading the page 3 empty rows with predefined cols (e.g. "name" and "age") and then you can enter some values. If you need 5 rows, ther should be an "add row" button to add a new row and there should be an "delete row" button each row.

[Example, what I mean](https://onaircode.com/javascript-js-datatable-examples/) (especially No. 4 is quit nice)

**minimal example** (basicaly just an hello world in flask)

*main.py*

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask import url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def load_index():
   return render_template('main.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

*main.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>

        *tabel here*
        
   </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately most tutorials I found just thematize how to *display* an datatabel out of an existing database or a pd dataframe...
I hope someone here knows a solution for my problem or has a hint. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can archive this with javascript. Just give your input form and table an id and grab the data from the form and edit your table. what you need to learn is how to get data from the form. for this you can use a FormData object

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
formData = new FormData(myForm);
```

you can learn more about this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

as for the table you probably want to use insertRow and insertCell:

```
// Find a <table> element with id="myTable":
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

// Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the 1st position of the table:
var row = table.insertRow(0);

// Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

// Add some text to the new cells:
cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
```

you can learn more about this topic here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp